# Removing duplicated rows in df based on column of matches

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

My `df` has a `link` column (of type list) that specifies if a record has a match within `df`(ie. if it has duplicates).

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:7,link=I(list(c(2,3),c(1,3),c(1,2),NA,NA,7,6)))

  id link
1  1 2, 3
2  2 1, 3
3  3 1, 2
4  4   NA
5  5   NA
6  6    7
7  7    6
```

I would like to subset `df` to keep only the first matched row (ie. with respect to order by id) for those rows with linked records. I want:

```
  id link
1  1 2, 3
2  4   NA
3  5   NA
4  6    7
```

I have tried a loop to store the `id` values of the rows to be removed from `df` in `to_remove`. It doesn't quite work at the moment and I feel I am overthinking this.

```
to_remove <- character(0)
for (n in 1:nrow(df)) {
  links <- df$link[[n]]
  if (all(is.na(links))) next # skip if no links available
  add <- ifelse(links %in% to_remove, NA,links)
  add <- add[!is.na(add)]
  if (length(add > 0)) to_remove <- c(to_remove,add)
}
```

Can I do this in a simpler way and avoid loops?

Comment: Why is the last row not included i.e. `7 6` ?

Comment: The value of `link` in the row with `id == 6` is `7`. This tells you that `6` and `7` are in fact the same record and I would like to keep only the first occurrence of matched records (ie. keep only `id==6` and discard `id==7`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id = rep(df$id, lengths(df$link)), link = unlist(df$link))
DT[DT[, .I[!any(id > link) | is.na(link)], by = id]$V1][, .(link = toString(link)), by = id]
```

gives:

```
   id link
1:  1 2, 3
2:  4   NA
3:  5   NA
4:  6    7
```

*Explanation*:

- First create a new data.frame/data.table by unlisting the lists in the cells of `df$link` and create a new data.frame/data.table.
- Then create an index for which the conditions for inclusion are met and select this subset.
- At last, convert the values in the link column back to a list for each id.

---

Or using a `dplyr`/`tidyr` combination:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  unnest(link) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(!any(id > link) | is.na(link)) %>% 
  summarise(link = toString(link))
```

which gives a similar result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     id  link
  <int> <chr>
1     1  2, 3
2     4    NA
3     5    NA
4     6     7
```

---

Or using base R:

```
dfn <- data.frame(id = rep(df$id, lengths(df$link)), link = unlist(df$link))
dfn <- dfn[!dfn$id %in% unique(dfn$id[which(dfn$id > dfn$link)]),]
aggregate(link ~ id, dfn, toString, na.action = na.pass)
```

Comment: this is great stuff, the explanations for the `data.table` solution did help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since the removal of row `x` depends on the values of `link` for all rows `1:x-1` vectorizing is hard. I would suggest looping once through all the rows and saving the (boolean) index of redundant rows. You were thinking right only your implementation is a bit rickety.

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:7,link=I(list(c(2,3),c(1,3),c(1,2),NA,NA,7,6)))

keep <- rep(TRUE, nrow(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  idx <- df$link[[i]]
  idx_larger_than_me <- idx[idx > i]
  print(idx_larger_than_me)
  keep[idx_larger_than_me] <- FALSE
}
df2 <- df[keep,]
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter, that's exactly what I was intending to do. Despite this being a functional answer, I didn't accept it since I was hoping I could avoid loops.

Answer (score 1):

If by

> first matched row

you mean with respect to order by `id`, then the following should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
result <- df %>% unnest(link) %>% 
                 filter(is.na(link) | link > id & !duplicated(link)) %>%
                 group_by(id) %>% 
                 nest(link, .key=link)
print(result)
### A tibble: 4 x 3
##     id             link
##  <int>           <list>
##1     1 <tibble [2 x 1]>
##2     4 <tibble [1 x 1]>
##3     5 <tibble [1 x 1]>
##4     6 <tibble [1 x 1]>
print(result$link)
##[[1]]
### A tibble: 2 x 1
##   link
##  <dbl>
##1     2
##2     3
##
##[[2]]
### A tibble: 1 x 1
##   link
##  <dbl>
##1    NA
##
##[[3]]
### A tibble: 1 x 1
##   link
##  <dbl>
##1    NA
##
##[[4]]
### A tibble: 1 x 1
##   link
##  <dbl>
##1     7
```

Notes:

1. First `unnest` so that `link`s are in separate rows (for same `id`)
2. The `is.na(link)` keep all rows that have no link
3. The `link > id` will keep rows for which the `link` is greater than the `id`. This will keep the first match when the order of match is by `id` since the linked rows will be greater than the id.
4. The `!duplicated(link)` will remove duplicates in the links.
5. Then, `nest`.